# jQuery Grid Layout Image Size

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery Plugin Grid-A-Licious (http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious). I want to show on Desktop Browsers the real Image Sizes.

```
$.Gal.settings = {
        selector: '.item',
        width: 450,
        gutter: 1,
        animate: false,
        animationOptions: {
            speed: 200,
            duration: 300,
            effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
            queue: true,
            complete: function () {}
        },
    };
```

https://github.com/suprb/Grid-A-Licious/blob/master/jquery.grid-a-licious.js

My next Problem is how I can set the Borders of the Images. By CSS I thought to make it with nth-child but this did not solve it.

Here is a link with my Example
http://jsfiddle.net/ajJpH/1/

Comment: What do you want to do with borders? Add borders? Animate borders?

Comment: Are you talking about the scroll bars?

Comment: No I just want to add borders around each image but without to have double borders.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Freewall. It is a cross-browser and responsive jQuery plugin to help you create many types of grid layouts include image layout. You can see the demo with image layout:

http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/image-layout.html

The project's github homepage is https://github.com/kombai/freewall

Comment: The Freewall plugin is used to create a masonry like css grid (the way mason stones are placed: place where it fits)